# nginx rewrite single URL wordpress

Tags: regex, wordpress, url, nginx, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite a single URL in nginx, but my regex fu is knackered.

What I'd like to do is rewrite:

> https://www.drake.org.uk/2012/07/os-x-mountain-lion-clean-install-gotcha-corestorage-encrypted-disk-issue

to become

> https://www.drake.org.uk/os-x-mountain-lion-clean-install-gotcha-core-storage-encrypted-disk-issue/

(The URLs without the 2012/07 aren't the same, as you'll see - I mucked it up and it's now a bit too late to change it without even more rewriting!)

I've tried:

```
rewrite ^/2012/07/os-x-mountain-lion-clean-install-gotcha-corestorage-encrypted-disk-issue 
https://www.drake.org.uk/os-x-mountain-lion-clean-install-gotcha-core-storage-encrypted-disk-issue permanent;
```

(above all one line)

and various combinations (including escaping the slashes), but nothing seems to work.

Is there a quick 'n' easy way of doing this?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this regex can help you:

```
/(\/?\d+\/)+/i
```

With substitution (`\`)

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/gH8fK1/1)